# Need to change only some lines in a file starting with string but also change part of that line

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a print file with different strings that the printer uses to place fields on a print form.  One of these fields has a week/day identifier but I want to replace this with the text of the day name instead.

I can extract the line and amend it via a script but this doesn't seem like the best way to do it and there could be multiple entries in the file so I'm hoping there's a SED solution

Script which hopefully explains what I'm trying to do -

```
DAYNO=`cat sedtest.txt |sed -n -e '/^\r~AF63/p'|cut -c 12`

case $DAYNO in
1) DAYTX="\"MON\""
;;
2) DAYTX="\"TUE\""
;;
3) DAYTX="\"WED\"" 
;;
4) DAYTX="\"THU\""
;;
5) DAYTX="\"FRI\""
;;
*) DAYTX="\"XXX\""
;;
esac

LINE63=`cat sedtest.txt |sed -n -e '/^\r~AF63/p'|awk -F '"' '{print $1 }'`
LINE63FIN="$LINE63$DAYTX"
```

Comment: It would be very useful to see some example lines from your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you already have day of the week as a number 0-6 (or 1-7 or whatever)? You don't need to convert the date? That makes it easy. Probably sed *can* help you!

Sed can take multiple search/replace patterns so you could simply look for each day of week individually.

By the way, using `cat` just to avoid `<` isn't generally a good idea, also using other tools such as cut only makes it more complex.

Personally, when easy to do so I stick with the search/replace and regex. So we replace `cut -c 12` with a regex that will capture the first 11 characters unchanged and select the 12th character. This is following the 6 character sequence `\r~AF63`, of course, so only 5 characters remain. I am not going to ask why the first character is a carriage-return. Lets just do the first 2 days of the week for now, and you can extend at leisure:

```
sed -e '/^(\r~AF63.{5,5})(1)/\1MON/' -e '/^(\r~AF63.{5,5})(2)/\1TUE/'  sedtest.txt
```

There are many other ways to drive `sed`, of course, which can find the line start match then do the replacement.

Comment: Thanks Gem - I got it sorted with a slight variation to this - `sed 's/^\r~AF63;"[0-9][0-9]\/1 /\r~AF63;"MON/'` and then piping this through TUE/WED versions to cover the week  (1st character is a CR because it it output designed to go to an old label printer)

Comment: I'm suggesting you just add more `-e` clauses to the above, but until you get one working, no point adding more :-)